# Two Select Options to get results and One search button

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using a fullcalendar in jquery to select and search events I want that each time they click the button a modal will appear, so when they select an event or a designated city a result will appear.  This is the HTML, 
These are the conditions:

1. User search a city : result will include all the cities
2. User will search the event: result will include an event.
3. User will search for both a city and event : result will include an
   event with the city.

The 2 conditions works , but the third one wont

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-name">
    <div class="modal-sandbox">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="modal-box">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Events</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="event-list">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="#eventdetails" class="order-details-table">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="calendar">&nbsp;</div>
<hr class="calendar">

<select id="search" class="modal-trigger" name="search" data-modal="modal-name">
    <option selected="selected" value="select">Select an Event</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
</select></p>

<select id="searchcity" class="modal-trigger" name="searchcity" data-modal="modal-name">
    <option selected="selected" value="select">Search a City</option>
    <option value="City1">City1</option>
    <option value="City2">City2</option>
    <option value="City3">City3</option>
    <option value="City4">City4</option>
    <option value="City5">City5</option>
</select>
<button id="searchnow">Search</button>
```

2. This is the code for Jquery, I want that when they select the values above a result would appear

JSON File

```
   {
        "title": "Tasting Festival",
        "start": "start date",
        "tags": "1",
        "imageurl": "",
        "products": [
          {
            "name": "City 1",
            "url": "",
            "time": "",
            "location": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "url": ",
            "time": "",
            "location": ""
          }

        ]
      }
$("#searchnow").click(function () {
    var selectedCity = $("#searchcity").val();
    var selectedEvent = $("#search").val();
    $.getJSON('events.json', 
        function (data) {
            render(selectedCity, selectedEvents, data);
        });
    });


      function render(selectedCity, selectedEvent, data) {
    $(".order-details-table").empty();

     $(data).each(function (i, v) {  
        if(v.products)
         $(v.products).each(function(index,p){

                    if (selectedCity == 'all' || p.name == selectedCity)  {

                                    $(".order-details-table").append('<tr><td class="o-box-name"><a name="detailsevent">' + p.name + '</a></td><td class="o-box-name">' + v.title + '<br><small>' + p.time + '</small><small>&nbsp' + p.location + '</small></td><td><a href="' + p.url + '" class="cancel-del-text" target=_"blank">Register!</a></td></tr>');


                                } if (selectedEvent == v.tags && selectedCity == p.name ){
                    $(".order-details-table").append('<tr><td class="o-box-name"><a name="detailsevent">' + p.name + '</a></td><td class="o-box-name">' + v.title + '<br><small>' + p.time + '</small><small>&nbsp' + p.location + '</small></td><td><a href="' + p.url + '" class="cancel-del-text" target=_"blank">Register!</a></td></tr>');

            }  if (selectedEvent == 'all' || v.tags == selectedEvent)  {

                                    $(".order-details-table").append('<tr><td class="o-box-name"><a name="detailsevent">' + p.name + '</a></td><td class="o-box-name">' + v.title + '<br><small>' + p.time + '</small><small>&nbsp' + p.location + '</small></td><td><a href="' + p.url + '" class="cancel-del-text" target=_"blank">Register!</a></td></tr>');



                                }
     });  
});
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. Do you want to open a modal when you click on the `button` search ? - https://jsfiddle.net/eq6tprz7/

Comment: Yes and return results

Comment: Can you try https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95192/

Comment: yes it worked what did you change?

Comment: Added bootstrap lib and created approprieted structure for modal. Also in your function, I added `$('#modal-name').modal('show');` to open the modal on button click. Please check your Json, you have syntax error.

Comment: still not working though

Comment: `{
"title": "Tasting Festival",
    "start": "start date",
    "tags": "1",
    "imageurl": "",
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "City 1",
        "url": "",
        "time": "",
        "location": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "",
        "url": "",
        "time": "",
        "location": ""
      }

    ]
  }`

In json URL =" error.

Comment: any specific error? If yes please specify

Comment: Question is updated @mayank

Comment: please tell us _specifically_ what is going wrong and/or what error you are getting. "Doesn't work" is not an adequate explanation. Thankyou.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eq6tprz7/11/ This is the fiddle

Comment: Just dumping us some code doesn't explain the problem. Please tell us more specifically what the issue is. Help us to help you! For what it's worth, the JSFiddle generates a warning because you try to call a fullCalendar method on an element which has no calendar, and also when you click "Search" there's an error because you didn't include the bootstrap modal functionality in the fiddle. So unless that's also an issue in your real code, that problem may be obscuring whatever is the real problem you want us to look at. Please make the JSFiddle reproduce the actual issue accurately. Thanks.

Comment: So for example, you search for Houston and then whiskey, the result should be Houston and then whiskey , or Chicago and Tequila result should be all Tequila Events in Chicago @ADyson

Comment: it's a logical error. For each data item, you first consider if it matches the city. If it does, you output it. Then you ask if it matches the city and the event. If it does, you output it. Then you ask if it matches the event. If it does, again you output it. So If any one of those if statements returns true, you output the event once. If it returns true for all 3, you output it 3 times. Your code needs to consider the status of the event against all the different criteria before deciding to output anything. Considering them one at a time not sufficient.

Comment: By the way this appears to have nothing to do with fullCalendar specifically

Comment: @chrissa you want to filter data from your JSON based on selection?

Comment: yes that's is what I want

Comment: As I have checked your json data output in Title you have "whiskey","cider" etc etc words in sentence and in product.name your have "Danver","Chicago" etc etc right so need to set condition based on that while you render your JSON data.

Comment: In your JSON data if you add the specific key for "whiskey","cider" it will be easy to filter the data, right now not all title contains the word whiskey or cider. i think tags key contain that data right!

Comment: @Chrissa Refer this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eq6tprz7/36/ your filter is ready.